# How to get id from route params and pass into a service

Tags: angular

A user clicks a button which should take them to a profile/:id page. In the profile component i try to get the id route params and pass it into my user service to return the user object to print in the html. However, this does not work.

main.component.html

```
  <button mat-icon-button color="accent" matTooltip="Account" [matTooltipPosition]="toolTipPosition" [routerLink]="['profile', user?._id]">
                <mat-icon>account_box</mat-icon>
          </button>
```

main-routing.module.ts

```
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: '../profile/profile.module#ProfileModule',
  },
```

profile.component.ts

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        let user_id = params.get('id');

        return this.userService.get(user_id);
    });
}
```

profile.component.html

```
{{ user?._id}}
```

profile-routing.module.ts

```
  {
        path: '',
        component: ProfileComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: HomeComponent,
                children:
                [
                    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
                    { path: 'moments', component: MomentsComponent },
                ]
            },

        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to your paramMap observable sequence. Observables are cold by default, so they do not run until you subscribe to them.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        let user_id = params.get('id');

        return this.userService.get(user_id);
    })
    .subscribe(res => this.user = res); // assuming user is being returned from this.userService.get()
}
```

Also you do not want `this.user = this.route.paramMap...`, this.route.paramMap is an observable sequence. So you are storing the sequence as opposed to the actual returned value. You want to store the user property after you receive the data in the .subscribe() method

Answer (score 2):

calling from html : replace 1 with your id

```
<a class="btn" href="#/profile/1">
```

main-routing.module.ts

```
{
  path: 'profile/:id',
  loadChildren: '../profile/profile.module#ProfileModule',
},
```

profile.component.ts

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.route.params.subscribe( params => console.log(params.id));
}
```